# django template filter for all variables of specific type

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In Django, I want to use a specific filter in all of my templates for all variables of a specific type.

For example let's say I want to use a filter that will convert date to Jalali Calendar if necessary based on user settings. In this case I want this filter to be applied to all variables I'll use in my templates that are a date.

I have a template called base.html which all of my templates extends it.

How can this be accomplished?

**UPDATE:** I'll use an example to clarify what I want to do exactly.

I have a model called Post which has field called `publish_date`. sth. like this.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    content = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now when I'm outputting a post using a template I want all of my posts `publish_date` and all of my other variables in the template which are representing a date to be filtered using a filter called `jalali_date`. which will format dates to sth I want.

I know how to use custom tags and filters but I don't know how to accomplish sth. like this using them(if it's possible to do this using them).

**UPDATE 2**:
Just to more clarify: I have already written jalali_date filter. the problem is how to apply it automatically to all variables in my template that are a date.

Comment: I will assume you have searched about the existing built-in template tags from django. I recommed you to read about create a custom template tag [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement this by a custom filter read about filters [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags), also below code maybe can help you:

```
import datetime, time

from django import template
import khayyam

register = template.Library()

def jalali_date(date):
    """Converts Date into JalaliDate"""
    timestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.timetuple(date))
    jalali_date = khayyam.JalaliDate.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    return str(jalali_date)

register.filter('jalali_date', jalali_date)
```

and then in template you can use it similar below(suppose templatetag file nam is jdate):

```
{% load jdate %}
...
{{ publish_date|jalali_date }}
...
```

but if you want to **automatically** recognize and change values of certain types you must use [`MiddleWares`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) (not filters), read snippet code about a custom `MiddleWare` [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/358/).

**Note**: for using non-builtin filters, you must add container app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: I know how to write custom filters. I've added more details of what I want to do to my post

Comment: I've already written jalali_date. How should I apply it to all date variables in my template? this is my question

Comment: You've written that it can be done using middlewares. could you explain how?

Comment: Read more about middlewares in related links in my answer.

Comment: I read about middlewares. But I still don't see how what I want can be done.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response